# How can "kinks" in electrical field and changing electrical and magnetic fields can work together to produce EM waves?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields, charge

I am trying to understand how electromagnetic waves are created and I've 2 explanations:

1. Vibrating electrically charged particle creates a changing electrical field, which creates magnetic field, which is also changing (I don't understand how exactly), so it creates electrical field, so it "powers" itself, which make electrical and magnetic fields traverse through space, and this is an EM wave.
2. When an electrically charged particle accelerates for a fraction of a second, the "far zone of it's electrical field doesn't know" that the particle moved because the information of his movement didn't reach the "far zone" yet (because the speed of light isn't infinite), so there is a gap between the "close zone" and the "far zone", which needs to be connected by "kinks", and those kinks are the EM waves.

I do not actually see how the second explanation fits with the first one, because apparently with the second one there are no magnetic fields involved in contrast to the first one, and the second one talks about any acceleration, and the first one insist on "vibrating".
Where am I mistaken?

Comment: I don't think it's possible for someone to easily answer your questions because they are quite vague. I mean you need to go and look at a book with a title like "Electricity and Magnetism" and you can find the answers to your questions in there, but the way you've phrased this question I don't see how anyone can realistically hope to give you an answer.

Comment: [What are Photons, EM radiation and EM waves](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/90646/what-is-the-relation-between-electromagnetic-wave-and-photon/253957#253957)